# Animating transitions of two subviews simultaneously with CATransition

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have my main view, and when a user taps a 'Show' button I want two things to happen:

1. Fade in a black `UIView` with alpha 0.5 covering the entire parent
   view. I'll refer to this as `darkenBackground`
2. Slide the view of a second view controller
   (`self.secondViewController.view`) on top of `darkenBackground`

When a user is finished, they tap 'Done' and the following happens:

1. `darkenBackground` fades out and is removed from the superview.
2. `self.secondViewController.view` slides out of the screen in the
   bottom direction and is removed from the superview.

All animations working simultaneously.

So far, I've been able to achieve the first part (sort-of), transition-in. This works fine. But when the user taps 'Done' the transition-out does not work as required. The problems I'm faced with are:

1. `darkenBackground` and `self.secondViewController.view` fade out and are removed, but
   `self.secondViewController.view` wasn't supposed to fade out! I tried animating only the second view but it simply disappears without animation.
2. When a user taps 'Show' for a **second** time
   (transition-in), the view from the previous transition
   appears before the animation takes place. It doesn't look like it
   was removed from the superview previously.

Here is my code:

When a user taps 'Show':

```
- (IBAction)showSecondView {

    darkenBackground = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [darkenBackground setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [darkenBackground setAlpha:0.5];

    self.secondViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    self.secondViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [CATransaction begin];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];

    CATransition *animation2 = [CATransition animation];
    [animation2 setDuration:0.5];
    [animation2 setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
    [animation2 setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
    [animation2 setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [self.view addSubview:darkenBackground];
    [self.view addSubview:self.secondViewController.view];

    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"darkenBkgFadeIn"];
    [[self.secondViewController.view layer] addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"ShowSecondView"];

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

When a user taps 'Done' (A function defined in the `secondViewController.m` class where it refers to the main view controller variables through delegate):

```
- (IBAction)hideSecondView {

    [CATransaction begin];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];

    CATransition *animation2 = [CATransition animation];
    [animation2 setDuration:0.5];
    [animation2 setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation2 setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [animation2 setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [self.myParentController.darkenBackground removeFromSuperview];
    [self.myParentController.secondViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    [[self.myParentController.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"darkenBkgFadeOut"];
    [[self.myParentController.secondViewController.view layer] addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"RemoveSecondView"];

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Ultimately I want to show the view in the same way that the `TWTweetComposeViewController` modal view appears, where the background darkens and the controller appears. I could just use a modal view controller, but the issue I have with that is that when presenting the view controller it only 'appears' and does not slide from the bottom (since I require a semi-transparent background, I cannot use the default context for the modal view).

Cannot figure this one out, would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `self.myParentController.view` used in `-hideSecondView` is the same view as `self.view` in `-showSecondView`. If this is the case, then you're applying a transition to the whole view here:

```
[[self.myParentController.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"darkenBkgFadeOut"];
```

You added `self.secondViewController.view` as a subview of `self.view` in `-showSecondView`, so when you later perform a transition on `self.myParentController.view`, it's going to apply the transition to all its subviews (i.e., `self.secondViewController.view`) as well.

Instead of applying the transition to `self.myParentController.view` in `-hideSecondView`, apply it directly to `darkenBackground`:

```
[[self.myParentController.darkenBackground layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"darkenBkgFadeOut"];
```

If I recall correctly, you can apply `CATransitions` when layers are added/removed to/from a view. If not, then you'll have to wrap `darkenBackground` in a separate container view and perform the transitions on that so it doesn't include `self.secondViewController.view` when you do the fade out.